# Atomic compare exchange. Is it correct?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I want to atomically add 1 to a counter under certain conditions, but I'm not sure if following is correct in a threaded environment:

```
void UpdateCounterAndLastSessionIfMoreThan60Seconds() const {
    auto currentTime = timeProvider->GetCurrentTime();
    auto currentLastSession = lastSession.load();
    bool shouldIncrement = (currentTime - currentLastSession >= 1 * 60);

    if (shouldIncrement) {
        auto isUpdate = lastSession.compare_exchange_strong(currentLastSession, currentTime);
        if (isUpdate) 
            changes.fetch_add(1);
    }
}

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Time> timeProvider;
    mutable std::atomic<time_t> lastSession;
    mutable std::atomic<uint32_t> changes;
```

I don't want to increment changes multiple times if 2 threads simultaneously evaluate to shouldIncrement = true and isUpdate = true also (only one should increment changes in that case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is at least a bit iffy, as following scenario will show:

First thread 1 does these:

```
auto currentTime = timeProvider->GetCurrentTime();
auto currentLastSession = lastSession.load();
bool shouldIncrement = (currentTime - currentLastSession >= 1 * 60);
```

Then thread 2 does the same 3 statements, but *so that currentTime is more than it just was for Thread 1*.

Then thread 1 continues to update `lastSession` with it's time, which is less than thread 2's time.

Then thread 2 gets its turn, but fails to update `lastSession`, because thread 1 changed the value already.

So end result is, `lastSession` is outdated, because thread 2 failed to update it to the latest value. This might not matter in all cases, situation might be fixed very soon after, but it's one ugly corner which might break some assumptions somewhere, if not with current code then after some later changes.

---

Another thing to note is, `lastSession` and `chnages` are not atomically in sync. Other threads occasionally see changed `lastSession` with `changes` counter still not incremeted for that change. Again this is something which might not matter, but it's easy to forget something like this and accidentally code something which assumes they are in sync.

---

I'm not immediately sure if you can make this 100% safe with just atomics. Wrap it in a mutex instead.

Comment: Yes, minutes is misleading in the context of the example. Updated the sample code, stil the issues with multiple updates to former "minutes"

Comment: As far as I can see, `minutes`/`changes` will not be updated, unless `compare_exchange_strong` succeeded. So there's no chance of it getting updated too many times. Two threads can't update the time value from same previous value, because after it is atomically updated, the other thread sees different value and update fails.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that I was thinking in the first place :-). Changes is guaranteed to update only once indeed

Comment: In my case the fact that a possibly older lastSession is written is no problem as long as +1 is done correctly (once). I think that justifies using no locks on a concurrent server

Comment: Unless you have a lot of threads calling that functions hundreds of times per second, I would play it safe and use a mutex... You could still use atomics to read the value in consistent state, and only use mutex to protect modification. Well, except if it's a problem if `lastSession` and `changes` are not atomically in sync, but that's problem with your current code too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no C++ expert, but it looks to me like you've got a race condition between the evaluation of "isUpdate" and the call to "fetch_add(1)".

So I think the answer to your question "Is this thread safe?" is "No, it is not".

Comment: If this thread is the thread that correctly updated lastSession (if that is correct) than fetch_add should be ok for that thread.

Comment: @Ghita Yes, but by "correct in a threaded environment" I took you to mean cases where 2 or more threads may be running concurrently. If threads 1 and 2 both evaluate isUpdate before either one calls fetch_add(), then both will call fetch_add(), which is what you don't want.

Comment: fetch_add() is done only by 1 thread because compare_exchange is an atomic read-modify-write operation